# Is it safe to simply EXTEND a boot partition with gparted without moving it

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I have an old, very solid computer currently running Ubuntu 18.04 server on which I originally made the boot partition too small, and am constantly running out of space on it when doing kernel upgrades. The boot partition is /dev/sdb1. I used gparted from a live USB to shrink /dev/sdb2, an oversized swap partition, by 200Mb from the bottom, moving any metadata in the process. All went well, and now I have 200Mb of free space just above my boot partition.

Is it safe to use gparted to simply append this free space onto sdb1 without moving anything? I assume that gparted is smart enough to do the proper partition formatting so that the added space in sdb1 is immediately usable, and that because nothing was actually *moved*, that the grub configuration will remain unchanged. Does this sound reasonable?

Important data on the system is on RAID-1 arrays on other drives so it's safe, but I don't want to have to rebuild the OS by doing something which would render the system unbootable.

Comment: It **should** work. Always have system backup before trying any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

In GParted you can only extend partitions (and shrink for that matter) on the right side. So if your free space is on the right side it is easy.
 If it is on the left, move the partition you want to extend to the left, so the free space is on the right side of it. Then extend. As statet before make backups.
If you use a laptop make sure it is plugged into the power supply or you have sufficient power to complete the proces (as it is only a small partition it shouldn't take long).